# How do I read a gzip file in f#?

Tags: f#, gzip

I have a standard gzip file that I would like to read into a sequence in F#. I found an example of how to read a regular file in Expert F# 3.0 and a reference the the [.NET GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the MSDN documentation, but I am new to F#/.NET and do not know how to combine the two to get the desired result.

Specifically, how do I modify the code below to read a gzipped file such as test.txt.gz?

```
let linesOfFile =
    seq {use reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("test.txt"))
         while not reader.EndOfStream do
             yield reader.ReadLine()}
```

Comment: Do you wish to uncompress the file that you read in, or do you want to read in the compressed as is without decompressing it?

Comment: I would like to read in the decompressed file. If "test.txt" is the decompressed file, and "test.txt.gz" is the compressed file, I would like a function that when applied to "test.txt.gz" gives me the same thing as linesOfFile above.

Comment: Just change it to `new StreamReader(GZipStream(File.OpenRead("test.txt"), CompressionMode.Decompress))`.

Comment: Okay, thanks Daniel. I see now how it works. GZipStream is a stream that I can wrap in StreamReader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(posting comment as answer)

`GZipStream` inherits `Stream`, so merely pass your underlying stream to its constructor along with the `CompressionMode`:

```
new StreamReader(
  GZipStream(
    File.OpenRead("test.txt"), 
    CompressionMode.Decompress))
```